# Ionic3 / Firebase / List-filter

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

since few days I get information about how to list from Firebase db.

```
this.items$ = data.getNewsList()
let user = this.auth.getName();
console.log('user > ', user);

let ref = firebase.database().ref('/ftnews')

    ref.orderByChild("owner_name")
    .equalTo(user).on("child_added", 
        function(snapshot) 
        { 
        console.log('selection > ', snapshot.key);
        return ref
        }
    );

   this.selectedNews = data.getNewsList(), 
    ref => ref.orderByChild('owner_name').equalTo('user');
    console.log('this selectedNews >', this.selectedNews);

   this.selectedNews.subscribe(
      (selectedNews) => { 
          console.log("result here >", selectedNews);
          return selectedNews;
      } 
   );
```

I stil get the right result on the console, but are unable to display the result on the ionic page ?

Any tutorials to help ?
thanks.

Here is the html :

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list text-wrap> 
     <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of snapshotData">
        {{ item.owner_name }} — {{ item.title }}
      </li>
     </ul>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list>
     <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let item of selectedNews | async">
         here : {{ item.owner_name }} — {{ item.title }}
       </li>
     </ul>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items$ | async | orderBy: 'postedAt' 
     : true; let i = index" (click)="itemTapped(item)">
      <ion-thumbnail item-left *ngIf="item.thumb && item.thumb[0]">
          <img src={{item.thumb[0].url}}/>
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>{{ item.owner_name }} — {{ item.title }}</h2>
      <p class="as-post-meta">{{ item.postedAt | date:'short'}}</p>
      <p>{{ item.body | truncate : 70}}</p>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: can you share how are you trying to display the result? share your template basically and ts file

Comment: Which one data you have to access show some sample data. And point out which variable data.

Answer (score 0):

I stil get the right result on the console, but are unable to display the result on the ionic page ?

From your question, Iam understand few things you have to store value to variable.Then you can easily access in html page.

Typescript file,

```
Public snapshotData:any[]=[];


this.items$ = data.getNewsList()

let user = this.auth.getName();
console.log

let ref = firebase.database().ref('/ftnews')

    ref.orderByChild("owner_name")
    .equalTo(user).on("child_added", 
        function(snapshot) 
        { 
        console.log('selection > ', snapshot.key);
//here Iam assigned value to a variable
this.snapshotData=snapshot.key;
        return ref
        }
    );
```

If your result may an array of object In your html page you can display like this

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of snapshotData">

    {{  Item.name }}
    </li>
```

If you give some sample data I will show how to display in html page.

I have a doubt also Iam pointed out in this answer variable is correct or wrong?. If wrong tell me I will change my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I get the Error : Cannot set the property 'snapshotData' of null.

Comment: What value you got this line  console.log('selection > ', snapshot.key);

Comment: with le lines :
3 times :
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot set property 'snapshotData' of null
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:272:31
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128610:22
    at exceptionGuard (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:17893:9)
    at EventList.raise (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:132123:42)
    at EventQueue.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ ..